# simple routing in yii framework 1

Tags: yii, routes

I am new to yii framework.I have a page controller and contact_us action then url become is **site_url/page/contact_us** but i want to it should be **site_url/contact_us**. i want to know how to set route for this and in which file.

```
class PageController extends SiteController
        {
           function actionContact_us()
            {
                //something ; 
            }
        }
```

I m using this code :-

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'appendParams' => false,
            'caseSensitive'=>false, 
            'rules'=>array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'application.components.IndexUrlRule',
                    'connectionID' => 'db',
                ),
                array(
                        'contact_us' => 'site/page/contact_us',
                          ),
                array(
                        'class' => 'application.components.PageUrlRule',
                        'connectionID' => 'db',
                ),                      
                '<_c:index|trade|page>'=>'<_c>/index',
                'page/<page_id:\d+>' => 'page/show'
            ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure in your **Url Manager** in config file like this -

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            'contact_us'=> 'site/page/contact_us',
        )
    )
```

After your url -

*www.example.com/contact_us*

Comment: it is not working. i updated my question with what i am using in config file

Comment: @Deepaksaini this is wrong way to implementation dude, you can't write code in rules section.

Comment: set this - `'site/page/<action:\w+>'=>'site/<action>'` in rules array.